# Code Flow Authentication Angular 8 unable to get access token

Tags: angular, typescript, post, single-sign-on, angular8

In my code I am implementing SSO login. I have `auth.service`, which is given inside `app initializer` in app.module.ts. I have code flow, I am able to hit the service, get the code inside the url. Now I want to send a post request which carries a `body` that will return the access token. But as soon as post request is hit, the application refreshes and the process starts again. It exits the loop after trying multiple times and say `Authorization code has expired`. My code is as follows:
**inside app.module.ts file**

```
export function appsso(http: HttpClient, authService: AuthService) {
return (): Promise<any> => {
return authService.init()
};

 {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appsso, deps: [HttpClient, AuthService], multi: true}
```

**inside authService file**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  init() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('init is called');
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {              // if we have token, its good to go
      console.log('good to go');
      } else {
      if (!location.href.includes('?code=')){        // if url contains code
         const params = [
        'response_type=code',
        'client_id=abcde',
        'scope=openid profile',
        'redirect_uri=https://URLhere/a.0/',
        ];
        location.href = 'https://secureURLhere/authorize?' + params.join('&');      
        return 
      } else {
        const code = window.location.href.split('=')[1];     //split url to extract code
        return this.getAuthToken(code).then(data): any => {
        localStorage.setItem('tokenData', data);
        console.log('access token received');
        resolve();}, error ((err) => {
        console.log ('error occured');
        reject();
      }    
    }
  }
getAuthToken(code: string){
  let body: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
  body = body.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
  body = body.append('code', code)
  body = body.append('client_id', 'abcde')
  body = body.append('client_secret', '12345');
  return this.http.post('https://secureURLhere/token', body).toPromise();   //making post call
}
```

Also the `header` is of type `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`When the Post API is hit, I should be able to get the access token. But it refreshes the app again. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Where do you store token in localStorage?

Comment: i have made the edit. omitted the line by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things that won't work in your code. For every end of the if statements you should return something. Otherwise it might get stuck. Also, sometimes you need to return in an if-statement to prevent nesting, by doing this your code will be easier to read (most of the time)

The code for your service will be something like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface AuthTokenResponse {
  access_token: string;
  id_token: string;
  expire_in: number;
  token_type: string;
}

class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  init() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      // Check if token is in local storage
      if (localStorage.getItem('auth-token')) {
        // We have a token, so can continue
        return resolve();
      }

      // Create object from the URL query parameters
      const params = window.location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split('&')
        .reduce((prev, current) => {
          const [key, value] = current.split('=');
          if (key || (value !== undefined && value !== null)) {
            prev[key] = value;
          }
          return prev;
        }, {});

      // Check if the code is in the parameters
      if (params && params['code']) {
        // Code present. Use code to get Auth token
        return this.getAuthToken(params['code']).then(
          (data) => {
            // We get a access token. Save the token to the local storage
            localStorage.setItem('auth-token', JSON.stringify(data));
            resolve();
          },
          (err) => {
            // Something went wrong
            reject();
          }
        );
      }

      // No token was present in the parameters, so redirect to SSO URL
      const redirectParams = new HttpParams()
        .set('response_type', 'code')
        .set('client_id', 'abcde')
        .set('scope', 'openid profile')
        .set('redirect_uri', 'https://URLhere/a.0/');

      location.href =
        'https://secureURLhere/authorize?' + redirectParams.toString();
      return reject();
    });
  }

  getAuthToken(code: string): Promise<AuthTokenResponse> {
    // Create the body used tor the URL to get the auth token
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .append('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
      .append('code', code)
      .append('client_id', 'abcde')
      .append('client_secret', '12345');

    // Send API Post request to SSO API
    return this.http
      .post<AuthTokenResponse>('https://secureURLhere/token', body)
      .toPromise(); //making post call
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit 1:*
Are you forgetting to "return" the promise from inside getAuthToken() method?
To me it looks like you are calling getAuthToken but getting null.

*Edit 2:*
I don't see anything with http.post that can cause app to refresh.
Only thing that can cause a reload is this line

```
 location.href = 'https://secureURLhere/authorize?' + params.join('&');
```

I feel issue is in the if condition here:

```
location.href.includes('?code=')
```

You might want to check that part in getAuthToken when you set the params. I think you are getting *&code=* instead of the expected *?code=*
I might be wrong.

*Edit 3*

Looking at the code I am guessing this is how the POST request is going:

```
POST https://secureURLhere/token HTTP1.1
(Below is body part)
grant_type=authorization_code&code=code&client_id=abcde&client_secret=12345
```

You can check it in Network tab of chrome dev tools to verify. Show it to your API person or check documentation of the API for what is expected. As for user defined headers, that should be of type HttpHeaders and should be third param of http.post() inside an object having the property called "headers". By default http client will set some headers for you.

For how it works, http.post returns an observable, which you can subscribe to. In your case you are casting observable to a promise and processing it further.
What kind type of observable? if you ask, well that depends on the actual response the Api is sending. It can be anything an observable of String (Observable), Observable of a Blob or Observable with full http response( Observable<HttpResponse>) etc. There are 15 different overloads of http.post. You specify how you want to read response. You can set responseType in http.post while creating request or use generics and typecast.
[Check the documentation for clarity.](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

Comment: I believe it is the issue with the if condition too. But, I am getting ```?code=``` only. When my post api is hit how is it supposed to catch and return the response? Also, is the body I am sending in post api is correct? what about the headers?